# java.lang.Object can't org.apache.spark.sql.Row[]

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive

My environment is spark_2.11.x java8

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
...
Row[] rows = spark.table("table").collect();
```

The build resulted is:

> Error:(41, 82) java: Incompatible types: can't convert
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Row[]

The document about `.collect()` return is `Row[]`. What could be the problem?

add:ide have no error or warning tips, but building

Comment: Can you share the imports from the top of your java file here, please? Thanks

Comment: import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.util.List; or import scala.collection.immutable.List;

Comment: two list type are occurs same error

Comment: The documentation clearly says that the result type is not Row[], but Object: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#collect--. It also says: For Java API, use collectAsList.

Comment: I GET IT! "Row[] rows = xxx.collect()" ide have no warning but building, the correctly way List<Row> rows = xxx.collectAsList, it works.T T

Comment: `Row[] rows = (Row[])   spark.table("table").collect();` try this. It's working in my code so,